# Yum can't find taglib-devel

Tags: linux, yum

I am trying to use taglib-ruby in an application, running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, using standard Amazon Linux, which requires taglib-devel installed on the server.  When running `yum install tablib-devel` I get `No package taglib-devel available.`

I know I've installed taglib on another EC2 instance before, but can't for the life of me remember how.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That just means that `yum` can't find it in its repository. You probably just need to add another repo to its list.

Alternatively, you can search for the rpm using an [rpm search engine](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=taglib-devel&submit=Search%20...) and then download and install the rpm manually:

```
rpm -i  taglib-devel-1.6.1-1.1.el6.i686.rpm
```